# Method used in After Insert, After Update and After Delete must fire only when once even though there are multiple DML(Add,update,delete)

Tags: apex, visualforce, trigger, dml-operations

I have visualforce page which allows user to perform mixed dml (add/delete/update) on records at once. I have a method(that creates a opportunitylineitem showing the aggregate sum of records) is used in after insert, after update and after delete methods which will execute based on the dml performed on the vf page followed by apex trigger. If there is a use case where user insert a record & updates the existing record then the method executes twice both in after insert and after update which ends up in creating dupe records (in this case 2 opplineitem records where 1 opplineitem shows the calculated value of inserted records while 2nd one which is created in after update is showing both inserted & updated records. I'm struggling on how to just create only single Opplineitem (in this case 2nd one which has total of both inserted and updated records) showing all records. Please share your thoughts on how to approach this. Thanks!

[image]

VFP Controller

```
    public Opportunity opp;
    public List<Vendor_Fees__c> VendorFeesList {get;set;}
    public Integer rowIndex {get;set;}
    public List<Vendor_Fees__c> delVendorFees {get;set;}
    public OpportunityVendorFeesController_AC(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
        opp = (Opportunity)controller.getRecord();
        VendorFeesList = [Select Id, Vendor__c, Estimated_Fee__c, Estimated_Tax_Amount__c, Actual_Fee__c, Fees__c, Fee_Value__c, Fee_Type__c, Fee_Calc__c, Opportunity__c, Tax_Amount__c FROM Vendor_Fees__c where Opportunity__c = : opp.Id];
        delVendorFees = new List<Vendor_Fees__c> ();
    }
    public void addRow(){
        VendorFeesList.add(new Vendor_Fees__c(Opportunity__c = opp.Id));
    }
    public PageReference save(){
        try{
            upsert VendorFeesList;
            system.debug('delVendorFees-----'+delVendorFees);
            if(!delVendorFees.isEmpty()){
                delete delVendorFees;
                delVendorFees.clear();
            }
            VendorFeesList = [Select Id, Vendor__c, Estimated_Fee__c, Estimated_Tax_Amount__c, Actual_Fee__c, Fees__c, Fee_Value__c, Fee_Type__c, Fee_Calc__c, Opportunity__c, Tax_Amount__c FROM Vendor_Fees__c where Opportunity__c = : opp.Id];
            //return (new ApexPages.StandardController(accounts)).view();
            PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/apex/OpportunityVendorFees_VF');
            pageRef.getParameters().put('id',opp.Id);
            return pageRef;
        }catch(DMLException de) {
            Apexpages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.SEVERITY.FATAL, de.getDmlMessage(0)));
            return NULL;
        }
    }
    public void deleteRow(){
        rowIndex = Integer.valueOf(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('rowIndex'));
        if(VendorFeesList[rowIndex].Id != null)
            delVendorFees.add(VendorFeesList[rowIndex]);
        VendorFeesList.remove(rowIndex);                 
    }
enter code here
```

//Triggerhandler

```
public void OnAfterInsert(List<Vendor_Fees__c> newVendorFees, Map<Id,Vendor_Fees__c> newVendorFeesMap){
    system.debug('After Insert vf------');
    oliPassAndCostUpsert(newVendorFees,newVendorFeesMap);
} 
public void OnAfterUpdate(Vendor_Fees__c[] newVendorFees, Map<Id,Vendor_Fees__c> oldVendorFeesMap,Map<Id,Vendor_Fees__c> newVendorFeesMap){
    system.debug('After update vf------');
    oliPassAndCostUpsert(newVendorFees,newVendorFeesMap);
}

public void OnAfterDelete(Vendor_Fees__c[] oldVendorFees, Map<Id,Vendor_Fees__c> oldVendorFeesMap){
    system.debug('After delete vf------');
    oliPassAndCostUpsert(oldVendorFees,oldVendorFeesMap);
}
```

[image]

[image]

//Apex Trigger

```
trigger VendorFeesTrigger_AT on Vendor_Fees__c (before insert, before update, after insert, after update, after delete) {
Triggers_Configutaion__mdt apexTrigger = [Select Id, Active_Trigger__c From Triggers_Configutaion__mdt WHERE MasterLabel ='Vendor Fees Trigger'];
if(apexTrigger.Active_Trigger__c){
    VendorFeesTriggerHandler_AC handler = new VendorFeesTriggerHandler_AC();
    //Before Insert
    if(Trigger.isInsert && Trigger.isBefore){
        handler.OnBeforeInsert(Trigger.new);
    }
    
    // After Insert 
    else if(Trigger.isInsert && Trigger.isAfter){
        handler.OnAfterInsert(Trigger.new, Trigger.oldMap);
    }
    
    // Before Update 
    else if(Trigger.isUpdate && Trigger.isBefore){
        handler.OnBeforeUpdate(Trigger.new, Trigger.oldMap, Trigger.newMap);
    }
    
    // After Update 
    else if(Trigger.isUpdate && Trigger.isAfter){
        handler.OnAfterUpdate(Trigger.new, Trigger.oldMap, Trigger.newMap);
    }
    
    /*
    // Before Delete 
    else if(Trigger.isDelete && Trigger.isBefore){
        //handler.OnBeforeDelete(Trigger.old, Trigger.oldMap);
    }
    */
    // After Delete 
    else if(Trigger.isDelete && Trigger.isAfter){
        handler.OnAfterDelete(Trigger.old, Trigger.oldMap);
    }
    /*
    // After Undelete 
    else if(Trigger.isUnDelete){
        //handler.OnUndelete(Trigger.new);
    } */      
}else{
    system.debug('----Skipped Account Trigger----');
}
```

Comment: Your trigger should work in the presence of multiple DML operations at once. It's not your Visualforce page that's the matter, it's the `oliPassAndCostUpsert` method that needs to be fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the response. When you say the method needs to be fixed, there are no dml operations done on Vendor_Fees__c object that could lead to this behavior. Even though there is one dml with in that methd on lineitem, I have tested that by removing that dml statement & its still the same(Attached the debug logs snapshot). So the issue here is how to prevent the trigger handler logic from entering this method whenever there is an Insert, Update & delete are performed in single transaction. The Priority of calling the method (ONLY ONCE) will be 1.AfterDelete, 2.AfterUpdate, 3.AfterInsert

Comment: Your trigger appears to only be firing once. This further supports my hypothesis that the problem is in your trigger logic method, and not any of the code you've shown here.

Comment: shared the apex trigger that calls the handler. Let me know what you think

Comment: SAVE mthd frm VFpage
       
upsert VendorFeesList; //Trigger fires here and enters both insert&update handler methods while the update method will have the accurate sum of all(Inserted+updated)records
       if(!delVendorFees.isEmpty()){
              delete delVendorFees; //Enters deleteMthd
How do we let the system know that if the dml of Inert & update happens on a record using upsert THEN only call the logic in after update trigger event.
Similarly if the dml of delete happens on a record THEN only call the logic in after delete bypassing the method call after insert & after update?